# linear differential(or recurrence) equation form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

It is well known that if one is dealing with a homogeneous linear differential/recurrence relation, a linear combination of the solutions is also a solution. But is a partial converse true? Namely, if we ignore the trivial solution, if the solutions satisfy linearity, is the equation giving rise to those solutions necessarily linear?